# Tkinter - get returned value from function called from window.bind

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I'm using Tkinter to catch keyboard press, to do that I wrote function called keyPress and I bind it to the window.
This function(keyPress) have a return value.
How can i get it ?

this is the function

```
def key_input(event):
    init_GPIO()
    r_time = 1

    key_press = event.char
    print ("Key :",key_press)
    sleep_time = 0.06

    curDis = distance("cm")
    print("Distance:", curDis)

    if curDis <15:
      print "less then 15 cm"
      reverse(r_time)
    elif key_press.lower() == "p":
        stop() 
    print("Stop")
    elif key_press.lower() == "w":
        forward()
    print("Forward")
    elif key_press.lower() == "s":
        reverse(r_time)
    print("Reverse")
    elif key_press.lower() == "a":
        turn_left()
    print("Left")
    elif key_press.lower() == "d":
        turn_right()
    print("Right")

    else:
        pass

    return curDis
```

and this is how i call the function

```
root.bind('<KeyRelease>',key_input)
```

thanks.

Comment: _"How can I get it?"_ Get it _where_? To the caller? Tkinter is the caller and it doesn't care about your return value. Your function is used as an event handler. Returning something from an event handler makes no sense, because the return value doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: You can assign return value to any outer variable, if you wish to use it later.